# Hibernate 4.0.0Final where is the SessionFactory.openSession(Interceptor interceptor)

Tags: java, hibernate

I try some code from [hibernate 4.0 interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors), which gives this code for use session-level interceptors:

```
Session session = sf.openSession( new AuditInterceptor() );
```

however, I check both the hibernate-core 4.0 source code and onlie [hibernate 4.0 java-doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html), the class `SessionFactory` does not have method `openSession(Interceptor interceptor)` , but [hibernate 3.6 java-doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) do have this method.

anyone knows where is the method move to? if deprecated, why the document still keeps it in tutorial document? and how should I use session-level interceptor in 4.0?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's implemented using Builder pattern now:

```
Session session = sf.withOptions()
                    .interceptor(new AuditInterceptor())
                    .openSession();
```

Comment: wtf. why there're no document methion this? where did you find this dude, you are document hero

Comment: @pinkdawn: Hibernate 4.x seriously lacks documentation now. [Hibernate 4.0 Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/index.html) is a leftover from Hibernate 3.x era, it doesn't reflect all the changes. It's to be replaced by a brand new [Hibernate Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/), which is not complete yet. To find the answer I just skimmed the Javadoc page and noticed a builder patter.

Comment: Not that I don't agree that the documentation is less than ideal, manuals generally do not mention "this is how you used to it, but now you do...".  Thats the job of change logs and migration guides.  The change logs are (1) put into the release download bundles and (2) referenced in release announcements and (3) permanently available via the Hibernate Jira.  The migration guides are listed at https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Hibernate3MigrationGuides ; https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40 for example